# Ubuntu server won't stop running processes

Tags: server, process, webserver

I have an Ubuntu 16.04 server with ISPConfig 3.1 and many websites installed.

For some reason the server started working too much on some processes with high load, and it gets too slow from time to time. I don't know what the running processes associated with this problem are, but it doesn't work well anymore.

I want to identify the running processes in order to figure out the solution. Hopefully someone can shed some light.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try `top` or `htop`. These applications will rank the running processes for you.

Comment: A fair bet is that you've gotten infected by some coin miner. Nuke and reinstall.

Comment: @StephenBoston The problem is that it won't let me use it because it's stuck and not responding